# Finding kewords in texts and create separate columns with the words

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe

I'm searching character strings based on the pattern : find the side before the keyword `car0-10` ( keyword car followed by number from 0 to 10). If I find the key words, I want to add them to new columns (i.e., `left` and/or `right`). If there is no keyword, I want to add 'x' mark or NA.

I need to find the phrase : `on the right car5` or `on the left car2`. These phrases have a common string pattern (left/right + car + number). I'm trying to figure out how to find them and add the car+number in the new columns.

```
text.v <- c("Max","John")
text.t <- c("True story about the area on the left car2, and a parking on the right car4 not far away","but there is a garage on the right car3 in another place")
#View(text.v)

text.data <- cbind(text.v,text.t)

View(text.data)
```

Data that I have :

```
|text.v|text.t|
|Max   | True story about the area on the left car2, and a parking on 
|John  |but there is a garage on the right car3 in another place
```

Expected result:

```
|text.v|text.t|left | right
|Max   | True story about the area on the left car2, and a parking on |car2|car4
|John  |but there is a garage on the right car3 in another place  |x|car3
```

I want to know methods to use regex or other ways, if there are any quick ways. As an extra feature, I wonder it is possible to add count of the key words (e.g., car2 appears twice on the right side of the word, `right`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Ronak's answer, I leave codes to handle your additional question. Here, I created a data set which is a bit more complicated than yours to think about the extra question. Similar to Ronak, I created two columns. The difference is that I created a string for each row including all cars. See the second row in `temp`, for instance.

For the extra question, I created another data frame. There is a possibility that you have multiple cars in `left` and `right`. I teased apart the character strings in `left` and `right`, and expanded the data frame. This is `out`. Then, I summarized the frequency of the cars for left and right side, and merged the two data sets.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

group_by(mydf, person) %>%
mutate(left = stri_extract_all_regex(str = text,
                                     pattern = "(?<=on the left )car[0-9]+?") %>%
              unlist %>% toString,
       right = stri_extract_all_regex(str = text,
                                 pattern = "(?<=on the right )car[0-9]+?") %>%
              unlist %>% toString) %>%
ungroup-> temp

temp

person text                                                                                      left  right     
<chr>  <chr>                                                                                     <chr> <chr>     
1 Max    Ana is on the left car2. Bob is on the right car4. They are not far away from each other. car2  car4      
2 John   I saw a garage on the right car1. There is a garage on the right car3.                    NA    car1, car3
3 Ana    There is a garage on the right car3. There is another garage on the right car3.           NA    car3, car3


dplyr::select(temp, person, left, right) %>%
       Reduce(f = separate_rows_, x = c("left", "right")) -> out

count(out, person, left, name = "left_total") %>%
full_join(count(out, person, right, name = "right_total")) 

person left  left_total right right_total
  <chr>  <chr>      <int> <chr>       <int>
1 Ana    NA             2 car3            2
2 John   NA             2 car1            1
3 John   NA             2 car3            1
4 Max    car2           1 car4            1
```

**Another solution**

Another way is to use the quanteda package with the tidyverse package. This is much simpler to find the word frequency. You still need to modify `docname`. But this is easy enough to do.

```
library(quanteda)

kwic(mydf$text, pattern = "car[0-9]+?",
     window = 1, valuetype = "regex") %>%
as.data.frame %>%
dplyr::select(docname, pre, keyword) %>%
count(docname, keyword, pre, name = "frequency")

  docname keyword pre   frequency
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <int>
1 text1   car2    left          1
2 text1   car4    right         1
3 text2   car1    right         1
4 text2   car3    right         1
5 text3   car3    right         2
```

**DATA**

```
  person                                                                                      text
1    Max Ana is on the left car2. Bob is on the right car4. They are not far away from each other.
2   John                    I saw a garage on the right car1. There is a garage on the right car3.
3    Ana           There is a garage on the right car3. There is another garage on the right car3.
```

Comment: Thanks !!!  you guys, both got the point :) appreciate this, may I ask you if there are some ways to do 1) faster than with RE ? 2) or other methods like tokenizing words then searching ? ( to make the whole process quicker? if you got some projects like that ... :) Also, where I can read about R memory requirements if there are around 10000 numerized A4 papers to analyse this way ?

Comment: @HappyMan You may want to check the quanteda package.

Comment: will check it :) thx , just i found that the NA are quantified in the code, is it normal ? like john and ana have NA but it shows 2 ? thank you buddy

Comment: @HappyMan Once you install the package, run this code with `mydf`. `kwic(mydf$text, pattern = "car[0-9]+?", window = 2, valuetype = "regex")`. This line may give you some inspiration.

Comment: @HappyMan I added the quanteda version for you. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Dear @jazzurro , I'm using the package and it'is working like charm , may I ask if 
1) the only way to present data to kwic is after i transform the text variable in mydf dataframe into character ? 

2) I need to find a way to put a 'conditional' to the 'Pre' parameter , because I want to include other keywords that will be quantified as 'left' or 'righ' , it's a list of keywords : leftmost, west,   ( for left) , and rightmost, rightest, east  ... etc( for right) if 
followed by car0-10 it will add it to the variable, is it possible to do with the quanteda ? thanks :)

Comment: to add more details to previous post, i'd like to add a sort of variable that represents Left and Right ( the 2 column names where I'll add found kw)

pre options =  if these kw come before car0-10
leftv =left, leftmost, west
rrightv=right, rightmost, east

post options= if these kw follow car0-10
leftv= on the left
rrightv=on the right

and scan through them to classify the found kw into these columns, put them in a conditional loop.... 

thank you for this, I have not found docs on the library homepage about performing these tasks...

Comment: @HappyMan For 1) Yes since you are dealing with text data. For 2) That is some good amount work to do with a sample data. I recommend you to try what you can do first. If you are still stuck, you want to write another question.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` and get the car number after "left" and "right" word respectively. This returns `NA` if no match is found, which can be changed later to whatever value we want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

text.data %>%
   mutate(left = str_extract(text.t, "(?<=left) car\\d+"), 
          right = str_extract(text.t, "(?<=right) car\\d+")) %>%
   select(left, right) #To display results

#   left right
#1  car2  car4
#2  <NA>  car3
```

**data**

```
text.data <- data.frame(text.v,text.t)
```

Comment: Thank you for these response, do you have some speed bench using different approaches ?